# Access violation when calling copied function

Tags: c++, windows, assembly

This is a program that copies a function onto the heap, sets it as executable and calls it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <csignal>
#include <Windows.h>
using std::cout;

#define RET 0xC3

void printBytes(void* start, uintptr_t numBytes) {
    std::ios_base::fmtflags savedFlags(cout.flags());
    cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0');

    bool lineComplete = false;
    for (unsigned int byte = 0; byte < numBytes; byte++) {
        lineComplete = byte % 4 == 3;
        cout << std::setw(2)
            << (int)*((uint8_t*)start + byte)
            << (lineComplete ? '\n' : ' ');
    }

    cout << (lineComplete ? "\n" : "\n\n");

    cout.flags(savedFlags);
}

uint8_t* findByte(void* start, uint8_t targetByte) {
    uint8_t* pByte = (uint8_t*) start;
    while (*pByte != targetByte) pByte++;
    return pByte;
}

uintptr_t findByteOffset(void* base, uint8_t targetByte) {
    uint8_t* byte = findByte(base, targetByte);
    return (uintptr_t)byte - (uintptr_t)base;
}

int main() {
    void(*function)() = [] { cout << "Hello world"; };
    uintptr_t size = findByteOffset(function, RET) + 1;
    cout << "function : " << function << "\n\n";
    printBytes(function, size);

    void(*functioncopy)() = static_cast<void(*)()>(malloc(size));
    cout << "functioncopy : " << functioncopy << "\n\n";

    if (functioncopy) 
    {
        memcpy(functioncopy, function, size);
        printBytes(functioncopy, size);

        DWORD oldProtect;
        VirtualProtect(functioncopy, size, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect);
        cout << "functioncopy()\n";
        functioncopy();
        VirtualProtect(functioncopy, size, oldProtect, &oldProtect);
    }
    else cout << "malloc(" << size << ") failed.";
}
```

When I run the program (in Release or Debug configuration, with or without optimization), it gives an access violation inside functioncopy(). I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work?! Can you point to any reference or document that claims that it's possible to copy a compiled function and execute the copy?

Comment: Are you doing this for fun? Or is there some problem that you're trying to solve. This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @ThomasJager Unfortunately I am not allowed to disclose details of production code.

Comment: @Discape It feels like a terrible idea to do this kind of thing in basically any production code. Even if it's part of an anti-cheat/obfuscation/anti-reverse-engineering system, think very carefully about how fragile you want your codebase to be. Alse, to get useful help towards solving your problem, you're likely going to have to find some way of demonstrating an equivalent problem.

Comment: @ThomasJager haha just kidding. I'm doing this for fun. So I made a naked function that uses inline assembly, the only problem occurs when calling printf. I just need to figure out how to fix that...

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JKtKCpyh worked for anyone curious

Comment: The key problem is that a function call will normally compile to a `call rel32`.  Copying that somewhere else means the same relative offset plus a different starting address will target a different absolute address.  (Or to call a DLL function, I think Windows will tend to use `call [RIP + rel32]` indirect call on x86-64, same problem.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to expect this to work. Whether or not anyone can think of a reason it wouldn't work, there is simply no reason to expect it to work. No standard or reference says that this should work, and expecting it to work is, to be blunt, crazy.

As just the most obvious ways it can fail: What if an `0xc3` happens to appear in the code for the function as part of something else, maybe the address of a helper function it calls? What if it doesn't use the `RET` instruction to return? What if the code for the function uses a relative jump to another function in the translation unit? What if the function jumps around and some of its code is located after the `RET` in memory? What if a million other things go wrong that I couldn't think of right this second?

This code is just absurd. It's not based on any rational engineering reasoning.

Comment: "uses a relative jump" -- Note that near immediate `call` instructions are also relative, so calling any other function generally belongs to this case too.

Comment: @Discape - *assembly* - and what this change ? only deep knowledge will make this work

Comment: @RbMm if I make it as position independent as possible, and patch the rest manually

Comment: @RbMm https://pastebin.com/JKtKCpyh looks like i have pretty deep knowledge then

Comment: @Discape - sorry, but no

Comment: @Discape To be precise, it now happens to do what you want it to do. If you want to describe that as working, you can, but most programmers won't agree with you.